# How to handle cases environment with long text in condition statement

Tags: math-mode, cases

I have the following code

```
\begin{align*}
H_k(\mathbb{RP}^n \times \mathbb{RP}^m) &\cong \left(\bigoplus _{i+j = 
k}\begin{cases*}
\mathbb{Z} & if $\mathcal{P}_1$ \\
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & if $\mathcal{P}_2 \cup \mathcal{P}_3$\\
0 & otherwise \\
\end{cases*}\right) \\ 
&\oplus \left(\bigoplus_{p+q = k-1} \begin{cases*}
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & if $q$ is odd and $0 <q < m$ and $p$ is odd and $0 < p < n$\\
0 & otherwise \\
\end{cases*}\right)
\end{align*}
```

which produces the following output (the framed box code is not in the above)

[image]

Now the problem is that I want the long condition in the cases evironment to fit in the box and still appear next to the Z/2Z in a natural way.

The best I can get is the following after making a minor change to the above code and this doesn't look very natural as it looks we have two separate conditions in the cases environment and it's just that one of the conditions is next to an empty block of blank space.

In this case what is the best way to handle this situation?

[image]

Comment: Please, make your code compilable and add the frame problem to it!

Comment: To reduce the text a bit, instead of `if $q$ is odd and $0 <q < m$ and $p$ is odd and $0 < p < n$` you could say `if $q$ and $p$ are odd and $0 <q < m$ and $0 < p < n$`.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the first picture and I have inserted the [`geometry`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf) package and I have completed your initial code that was incomplete.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
H_k(\mathbb{RP}^n \times \mathbb{RP}^m) &\cong \left(\bigoplus _{i+j = 
k}\begin{cases*}
\mathbb{Z} & if $\mathcal{P}_1$ \\
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & if $\mathcal{P}_2 \cup \mathcal{P}_3$\\
0 & otherwise \\
\end{cases*}\right) \\ 
&\oplus \left(\bigoplus_{p+q = k-1} \begin{cases*}
\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} & if $q$ is odd and $0 <q < m$ and $p$ is odd and $0 < p < n$\\
0 & otherwise \\
\end{cases*}\right)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```